# I have created a 2 multiselect list and it is displaying in one single text box will I run the programme

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jquery-select2, multi-select

I have created 2 multiselect list for Contact Group details and employee details in a create() function, while the view for both of them are different at runtime it appears in 1 textbox.. Not sure why is it happening?

I tried changing the view, and the controller as well here is the code for my controller:

```
// GET: DistributionLists/Create

        public ActionResult Create()

        {   //LIST FOR CONTACT DETAILS

            var contact = db.Contact;

            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var item in contact)

            {

              items.Add(new SelectListItem

            {

              Value = item.EmployeeId.ToString(),

                Text = item.EmployeeName.ToString(),

            });

 

            };

            ViewBag.Contacts = items;

            //  ViewBag.EmployeeId = new SelectList (db.Contact, "EmployeeId","EmployeeName");

 

            //LIST FOR CONTACT GROUP DETAILS

            var cg = db.ContactGroup;

            List<SelectListItem> ims = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var im in cg)

            {

                items.Add(new SelectListItem

                {

                    Value = im.ContactGroupID.ToString(),

                    Text = im.ContactGroupName.ToString(),

                });

 

            };

            ViewBag.cg = ims;

            return View();

        }

Here is the code for my View of the create page:

<div class="form-group">

         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId, "EmployeeName", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.DropDownList("Contacts", ViewBag.Contacts as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>

    </div>

 

    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactGroupId, "ContactGroupName", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.DropDownList("ContactGroupId", ViewBag.cg as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactGroupId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created two list in controller side. You have added all items in first listing

```
List<SelectListItem> ims = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var im in cg)

            {

                ims.Add(new SelectListItem

                {

                    Value = im.ContactGroupID.ToString(),

                    Text = im.ContactGroupName.ToString(),

                });

 

            };
  ViewBag.cg = ims;
```

just change items.Add into ims.Add in for loop

Answer (score 0):

> while the view for both of them are different at runtime it appears in
> 1 textbox..

From your code, you set all into `items`

```
 List<SelectListItem> ims = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var im in cg)

            {

                items.Add(new SelectListItem

                {

                    Value = im.ContactGroupID.ToString(),

                    Text = im.ContactGroupName.ToString(),

                });

 

            };

            ViewBag.cg = ims;
```

Change `items.Add` into`ims.Add` like :

```
ims.Add(new SelectListItem
    
                    {
    
                        Value = im.ContactGroupID.ToString(),
    
                        Text = im.ContactGroupName.ToString(),
    
                });
```

Comment: Hi @Ruchi Parmar , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Ruchi Parmar , You can see the answer activity, I  find the reason earlier than Dhaval Soni. I answered at Dec 15 at 2:35. But Dhaval Soni's answer is four hours later than me!!! And his is same with my answer!!!